# Native and cross compile using GNU make, embedded C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, embedded, cross-compiling

I'm working on a Makefile to make me able to native and cross-compile. choosing wether to compile for host linux or ti MSP432 should be done from command line:

```
$ make build PLATFORM=MSP432
$ make build PLATFORM=HOST
```

here's my Makefile that I tried to do it in:

```
include sources.mk

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),MSP432)
# Platform Overrides

# Architectures Specific Flags
LINKER_FILE = msp432p401r.lds
CPU = cortex-m4
ARCH = thumb
SPECS = nosys.specs

# Compiler Flags and Defines

CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
endif


ifeq ($(PLATFORM),HOST)

CC = gcc

endif


TARGET = c1m1
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map -T $(LINKER_FILE)
CFLAGS = -mcpu=$(CPU) -m$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS) -Wall -Werror -g -O0  
-std=c99
CPPFLAGs =


.PHONY: build
build: $(TARGET).out


.PHONY: clean
clean:  
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET).out $(TARGET).map

%.o : %.c
$(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
    OBJS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

$(TARGET).out: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

is this the right way to do that?

there's also another weird error happening when I compile using:

```
$ make main.o PLATFORM=MSP432
```

I get this error:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c main.c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -- 
specs=nosys.specs -Wall -Werror -g -O0  -std=c99 -o main.o
main.c:23:22: fatal error: platform.h: No such file or directory 
 #include "platform.h"
                  ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:64: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

and when I compile using this:

```
$ make main.o PLATFORM=HOST
```

I get this error, they are 2 different errors and I can't understand the reason behind this.

```
gcc -c main.c -mcpu= -m --specs= -Wall -Werror -g -O0  -std=c99 -o 
main.o
gcc: warning: ‘-mcpu=’ is deprecated; use ‘-mtune=’ or ‘-march=’ 
instead
gcc: error: missing argument to ‘-mcpu=’
gcc: error: missing argument to ‘--specs=’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m’
Makefile:64: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I posted those apparently different questions in 1 question, because I think they are affecting eachother.

this is also another headerfile that is called platform.h that has some conditionals to include some directives, which after the answer I think might be needed for compile time switches

```
#ifndef __PLATFORM_H__
#define __PLATFORM_H__

#if defined (MSP432)
#include "msp432p401r.h"
#define PRINTF(...)




#elif defined (HOST)
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRINTF(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)



#else
#error "Platform provided is not supported in this Build System"
#endif

#endif /* __PLATFORM_H__ */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I will answer the case when `PLATFORM` and `HOST` are the same:

> ```
> $ make main.o PLATFORM=HOST
> ```
>
> I get this error, they are 2 different errors and I can't understand the reason behind this.
>
> ```
> gcc -c main.c -mcpu= -m --specs= -Wall -Werror -g -O0  -std=c99 -o 
> main.o
> gcc: warning: ‘-mcpu=’ is deprecated; use ‘-mtune=’ or ‘-march=’ 
> instead
> gcc: error: missing argument to ‘-mcpu=’
> gcc: error: missing argument to ‘--specs=’
> gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m’
> Makefile:64: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
> make: *** [main.o] Error 1
> ```

This is due to your makefile: `CPU`, `ARCH` and `SPECS` are only set when 
`PLATFORM` is `MSP432`

So the line `CFLAGS = -mcpu=$(CPU) -m$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS) -Wall -Werror -g -O0 -std=c99` 
is evalued as `CFLAGS = -mcpu= -m --specs= -Wall -Werror -g -O0 -std=c99`

When `gcc` is invoked with `CFLAGS` as argument, which is incorrect.

To correct this, you can make theses little changes in your makefile:

```
include sources.mk

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),MSP432)
# Platform Overrides

# Architectures Specific Flags
LINKER_FILE = msp432p401r.lds
CPU = cortex-m4
ARCH = thumb
SPECS = nosys.specs

LDFLAGS_ARCH = -T $(LINKER_FILE)
CFLAGS_ARCH = -mcpu=$(CPU) -m$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS)

# Compiler Flags and Defines
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),HOST)

CC = gcc

endif


TARGET = c1m1
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map $(LDFLAGS_ARCH)
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS_ARCH) -Wall -Werror -g -O0  
-std=c99
CPPFLAGs =
```

Now, for the `main.c:23:22: fatal error: platform.h: No such file or directory`
You have to find where this file is locatted and eventually add it as a `gcc` option.

For instance, if the file `platform.h` is in `/some/directory`, you can add this 
option to `gcc` to help it to find it:

```
-I/some/directory
```

So in makefile, you can have this line:

```
CFLAGS_ARCH = -mcpu=$(CPU) -m$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS) -I/some/directory
```

---

**EDIT**

In comments, you add this problem for your question:

> that solved it the errors are consistent now, and here it is
>
> ```
>  In file included from main.c:23:0: ./include/common/platform.h:30:2: error:
>  #error "Platform provided is not supported in this Build System" #error "... *** [main.o] Error 1
> ```

Regarding the `platform.h` file, macro `MSP432` or `HOST` must be defined in order to run.

To define such macro, the `-D` option must be passed to `gcc`.

So the idea is to add some line to the makefile to define `MSP432` or `HOST` when necessary:

```
...
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),MSP432)
# Platform Overrides

# Architectures Specific Flags
LINKER_FILE = msp432p401r.lds
CPU = cortex-m4
ARCH = thumb
SPECS = nosys.specs

LDFLAGS_ARCH = -T $(LINKER_FILE)
CFLAGS_ARCH = -mcpu=$(CPU) -m$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS) -DMSP432 

# Compiler Flags and Defines
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),HOST)

CFLAGS_ARCH = -DHOST 

CC = gcc

endif
...
```

Comment: that solved it the errors are consistent now, and here it is: @next comment because too long

Comment: In file included from main.c:23:0:
    ./include/common/platform.h:30:2: error: #error "Platform provided is 
    not supported in this Build System"
     #error "Platform provided is not supported in this Build System"
      ^~~~~
    main.c: In function 'main':
    main.c:49:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'PRINTF' [- 
    Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
         PRINTF("%c", buffer[i]);
         ^~~~~~
    cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
    Makefile:67: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
        make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: also added to CFLAGS $(INCLUDES)

Comment: I got it in the morning and it was very helpful, thank you a lot. I just restrained from writing a comment because I was told twice to not write thanks comment xD

but here it is, a comment to confirm that these answers completely solved my problems.